# dart sdk is not configured even after setting flutter as well as dart sdk path

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, configuration

I'm so sick of setting up flutter!
So my android studio was working completely fine, I opened the default flutter program and then it started showing " dart-sdk is not configured " . I opened up the setting and i filled the location of dart sdk, to src/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk,and then when i applied it, it started showing too many error. Before you ask, my flutter sdk is already mentioned in flutter sdk path.

I dont know how to solve this problem. just a few minutes back only, i was able to run the web app easily.
Now it's showing add configuration. Pls help. Setting up android studio is so tough for flutter, one might as well quit in this very first step only !  [click on this link for the ss of all the errors in dart analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muwhA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opened the **flutter_projects** directory, open the flutter project **I_am_rich**  in android studio. It will fix your issue.